# vba loop through new files in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder in which CSV files from a FTP server are downloaded, I need to open the newest files and extract data from these. I do this vs the get data from text connection which works. The problem is that the folder has 15000+ files and I only need to open the ones from the last week, maybe a 100 files. 
Is there a way to open them in a certain order? then I could just say if timestamp file < then some time --> stop loop.

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. it is modified project of mine. Important is that you write to cell(5,1) the date you want the files to be filtered from. For example If you put 11.11.2015 only files younger than that will appear so no files will be written down. But if you put 1.1.1914 in cell 5,1 then all files will pop up. I dont know which file sare you opening. You didnt meantion types so I didnt put workbook.open into the code but I put an note in the code where some opening should happen. So Edit my code to your needs.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Save
DoEvents
Const ROW_FIRST As Integer = 2
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim intCountRows As Integer

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = "Vyberte prosím složku"
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName = "Vybrat složku"
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).AllowMultiSelect = True

intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

For Each Item In Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems
    If intResult <> 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Range("A:A").ClearContents
        Range("B:B").ClearContents
        Range("C:C").ClearContents
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "NAME"
        Cells(1, 2).Value = "PATH"
        Cells(1, 3).Value = "TAIL"
        Cells(1, 4).Value = "Last check:"

        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        intCountRows = GetAllFiles(strPath, ROW_FIRST, objFSO)
        Call GetAllFolders(strPath, objFSO, intCountRows)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
Next Item
Cells(1, 5).Value = Date
End Sub

Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal intRow As Integer, ByRef objFSO As Object) As Integer
DoEvents
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = intRow - ROW_FIRST + 1
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    inte = InStr(1, objFile.Name, "prázdný")
        If objFile.datecreated > DateValue(Cells(1, 5).Value) Then
'HERE SHOULD BE THE OPENING PROCEDURE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                
                Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFile.Name
                Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 2) = objFile.Path
                Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 3) = Right(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - InStrRev(objFile.Name, "."))
                i = i + 1
        End If
Next objFile
GetAllFiles = i + ROW_FIRST - 1

End Function

Private Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, ByRef objFSO As Object, ByRef intRow As Integer)
DoEvents
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object
Static veSpravneSlozce As Boolean

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        intRow = GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, intRow, objFSO)
        Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO, intRow)
Next objSubFolder
End Sub
```

the opening procedure should be in the middle sub